# How to display category page for custom post type (made with ACF)?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I just started to create a website working with ACF. On this website, I want to display Artworks by Category.

I want a Menu like that :

```
Home - Painting - Scultpure - etc...
      - Golf     - Old School
      - Social   - New era
```

But I can't figure out how to add in a Menu a category pages.

I already created a Taxonomie for the Category.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly share your code.
I assume you have created custom taxonomies with the CPT.
If so then make sure  you have the following in your snippet `'has_archive' => true,`

You'll have the following then, `sitename.com/{{taxonomy}}/{{slug}}`

And then just go ahead and create `archive-{{name}}.php` for a custom archive landing page else `archive.php` would do.

Comment: I don't really have code to share, I didn't create anaything I'm using Elementor for my archive.

I have created a custom taxonomies using Custom Post Type UI.

But I don't have this sitename.com/{{taxonomy}}/{{slug}} working and I don't know where to put the has_archive' => true
Actualy, the site is  : https://hp.nivo-web.fr/